# Local Maximum Point; Global Maximum Point

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima, multivalued-functions

Given is the function:

$f(x,y)=cos(x)+cos(y)$

Which of the following statements is correct?

**1. The function has a local maximum point in $P (0, 0)$**

This is correct, because the first order condition is fulfilled and the Hessian matrix $Hf$ is negative definite.

$ Hf (x,y) =\begin{pmatrix} -cos(x)&0\\0&-cos(y)\end{pmatrix} $

$ Hf (0,0) =\begin{pmatrix} -1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix} $

Eigenvalues are negative, so $Hf$ is positive definite $\Rightarrow$ The function has a local maximum in $P(0,0)$.

**2. The function has a global maximum point in $P(0,0)$**

How can I check it? 
Intuitively, this is correct, because of the rang of the initial function. But how can I prove it?

I think that I should check if the matrix is negative definite everywhere. Is this correct?

**3.  The function has a maximum point in $P(0,0)$ and this is the only one maximum point with the function value 2.**

This should be false, because the function is periodic, i.e. there are infinitely many maximum points with the value 2. How can I prove it?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For 2. Global maximum means that no where you get bigger. Can you prove $f(x,y)\leq2$ because then you would be done

Comment: 3. Just pick one other with the value $2$, that is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$-1\le \cos(x) \le 1$$ and $$-1\le \cos(y) \le 1$$ for all $(x,y)$

Adding the inequalities result in $$-2\le \cos(x)+\cos(y) \le2$$ for all $(x,y)$

Thus the local maximum at $(0,0)$ is a global maximum as well because of the above inequality.

As you mentioned the function is  periodic and this global maximum is attained infinitely many times.